# Pycharm - Internal Startup issue -java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find installation home path

Tags: java, python, pycharm, jvm

Internal Startup issue -java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find installation home path . Please make sure bin/idea.properties is present in the installation directory

[image]

I have path and java_home variables setup
**Java_home** points to ** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\ **

Comment: What's the full path of your IntelliJ is installed? Copy and paste the text -- don't post pictures.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this problem is a conflict between more than one product of Jetbrains. Please create a simple "idea.properties" file in the bin directory. If the problem not solved copy file from PHPstorm bin directory

Answer (score 1):

Inside your installation folder of PyCharm, you are probably missing the `idea.properties` file. I tried moving mine and I got the same error as you.

The path to the file was `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.4\bin` for me.

Comment: That's what I'm guessing. I'm not sure how to restore to its original.

Comment: Reinstall PyCharm.

Comment: I tried pasting idea.properties file in the folder location but still got another internal startup error saying 'InvocationTargetException'

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue after reinstalling IntelliJ IDEA. Despite having correctly set the JAVA_HOME variable and ensuring a clean Java installation, the problem persisted. Upon closer inspection, I discovered that I was attempting to launch IntelliJ using an outdated Windows shortcut that pointed to a previously uninstalled or corrupted directory.

My solution:

1. Closed all running instances of IntelliJ IDEA through the task
   manager.
2. Deleted the corrupted old installation folder.
3. Navigated directly to the new IntelliJ installation Executor using the
   following path: IntelliJ_Path/bin/idea64.exe
4. Launched IntelliJ IDEA using the idea64.exe executable to create a new shortcut.